# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in ComposerAPI.php on line 203

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm willing to use the **ComposerAPI** (https://github.com/kabachello/ComposerAPI) Package for my Project. But I got this error message with PHP 5.6

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) in ComposerAPI.php on line 203

With PHP 7.0 it's working fine. Can anybody help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the function at this line is `"require"` :

```
public function require(array $package_names, array $options = null, OutputInterface $output = null){ }
```

PHP 5 doesn't allow to use [reserved keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php) as function name.

As of PHP 7, the interpreter understands that is not the  [`require()`](http://php.net/require) function but a method of the class.

The [Documentation said](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) :

> As of PHP 7.0.0 these keywords are allowed as property, constant, and method names of classes, interfaces and traits, except that class may not be used as constant name.

So, this code cannot be used with PHP before the version 7.0.